# Select lexemes from unnested ts_vectors

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, unnest, tsvector

I try to select only lexemes from unnested ts_vector column:

```
select lexeme
from 
    (select unnest(to_tsvector('russian', description))
     from cards) as roots;
```

But it doesn't work, because SQL doesn't know anything about `lexeme` column. How can I select only lexemes from unnested ts_vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you found yourself:

```
SELECT (unnest(to_tsvector(description))).lexeme
FROM   cards;
```

The equivalent standard SQL form with the set-returning function in the `FROM` list is slightly more verbose, but easier to integrate in bigger queries:

```sql
SELECT d.lexeme
FROM   cards c
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(to_tsvector(c.description))) d ON true;
```

Related:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

#### Why? How?

Since Postgres 9.6 there is a second "overloaded" variant of `unnest()`. Quoting [the release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/release-9-6.html):

> - Add new functions for `tsvector` data (Stas Kelvich)
>
>   The new functions are `ts_delete()`, `ts_filter()`, **`unnest()`**,
>   `tsvector_to_array()`, `array_to_tsvector()`, and a variant of `setweight()`
>   that sets the weight only for specified lexeme(s).

Bold emphasis mine.

See:

```sql
SELECT proname, proargtypes::regtype[], prorettype::regtype
FROM   pg_proc
where  proname = 'unnest';
```

```
proname | proargtypes      | prorettype
--------+------------------+-----------
unnest  | [0:0]={anyarray} | anyelement
unnest  | [0:0]={tsvector} | record    
(2 rows)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=31953dd3a49f50100b5fac640a6f96df)*

The function is documented in [the manual among text search functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

> `unnest` ( `tsvector` ) → `setof record` ( *`lexeme`* `text`, *`positions`* `smallint[]`, *`weights`* `text` )

It returns `setof record` with named output columns. Hence we can refer to the column `lexeme` directly like we did.

Answer (score 3):

I found a laconic way to do it:

```
SELECT (unnest(to_tsvector(description))).lexeme
FROM cards
```